# JBoss will not stay running

Tags: java, jboss, centos

I have installed JBOSS AS 7.1 on my Centos box.

When running the command

```
./standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=192.168.1.26 -Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.1.26
```

I get the following output:

```
=========================================================================

JBoss Bootstrap Environment

JBOSS_HOME: /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

JAVA: /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/bin/java

JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+TieredCompilation -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

=========================================================================

16:51:54,714 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
16:51:55,128 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
16:51:55,211 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
16:51:56,816 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
16:51:56,829 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
16:51:56,859 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
16:51:56,890 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
16:51:56,950 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
16:51:56,974 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
16:51:56,996 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
16:51:57,085 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
16:51:57,092 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
16:51:57,094 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
16:51:57,186 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
16:51:57,206 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
16:51:57,252 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
16:51:57,357 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
16:51:57,498 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
16:51:57,885 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
16:51:58,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
16:51:58,165 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--192.168.1.26-8080
16:51:59,000 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory /usr/share/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments
16:51:59,127 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on /192.168.1.26:9999
16:51:59,154 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on /192.168.1.26:4447
16:51:59,277 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
16:51:59,370 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://192.168.1.26:9991
16:51:59,371 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 5160ms - Started 133 of 208 services (74 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Then it seems to hang.

While this is going on in the console I can access my java apps `IPADDRESS:8080/application`

I can access the admin concole.

When i go back to the Centos Console I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get out so I can do other stuff.

As soon as I do that I can no longer get to `IPADDRESS:8080/` or `IPADDRESS:8080/application`.

I am thinking this is not normal however I'm not seeing any errors in the logs, I have been searching google for the past couple days and cannot find an answer.

If anyone could shed some light on what is going on or what I have to do to keep JBoss running it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

If you've started it in a console already use ctrl + z to first suspend the process, then type in bg to background the process it will then stay running whilst the console session is still valid -

```
[Server:server-two] 21:14:08,067 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) started in 13601ms - Started 147 of 209 services (61 services are passive or on-demand)
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./domain.sh
#:~/JBoss/jboss-eap-6.2/bin$ bg
[1]+ ./domain.sh &
#:~/JBoss/jboss-eap-6.2/bin$
```

Running it as a service as suggested above would be the right thing to do for a proper environment, however you can alternatively start the script using nohup at which point it will remain running even if the console session is closed -

```
nohup ./standalone.sh -Djboss.bind.address=192.168.1.26 -Djboss.bind.address.management=192.168.1.26 &
```

Answer (score 0):

This all sounds pretty normal. The server is up and running.

However, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> just kills the process, so it's no longer reachable indeed.

What you want to achieve is: "How to run JBoss as a *service*?"

Try one of these how-tos:

- [Install JBoss 7.1 on CentOS 6](http://www.davidghedini.com/pg/entry/install_jboss_7_on_centos)
- [How to start JBoss AS 7 as a service on CentOS 6](https://community.jboss.org/thread/176251)

If you only want to do a quick test run, just append `&` to your command to send JBoss to the background.